# How can I add a class to a form element in Rails view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form generated by `scaffold`, and the `submit` button of this form is like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
```

How can I add a `class` to this `button` in standard `rails` way?

Comment: Please mark an answer as solution if it's correct. It helps other people in the community with the same problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, please use the code as below:

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'your-class-name' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the `:class` to the submit button.

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'my-class' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using rails 3,

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'class-name' %>
```

In latest rails 4 both are working fine

```
<%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'class-name' %>
```